# Read calendar events between 2 dates

Tags: java, android, events, calendar

I'm trying to read calendar events between 2 dates.

I use the Google developer example (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider), but it's not working.

Of course, I have events at the requested dates.

If I read all events for the calendar it's working, so a (bad) solution would be to check for each returned event if it's included in the interval...

Here is my code :

```
    final String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[]{
        CalendarContract.Events._ID,
        CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,
        CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
        CalendarContract.Events.DTEND,
    };

    final int PROJECTION_ID_INDEX = 0;
    final int PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX = 1;
    final int PROJECTION_DTSTART_INDEX = 2;
    final int PROJECTION_DTEND_INDEX = 3;

    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2020, 3, 18, 0, 0);
    long startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2020, 3, 24, 0, 0);
    long endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

    Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, startMillis);
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, endMillis);

    String selection = CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_ID + " = " + calID;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.READ_CALENDAR) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(builder.build(), EVENT_PROJECTION, selection, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Log.i (TAG, "ID=" + cursor.getLong(PROJECTION_ID_INDEX) + " Title=" + cursor.getString(PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

The builder is correctly initialized (something like that : "content://com.android.calendar/instances/when/1584486000000/1584918000000")

The code below is returning fine all events for the calendar :

```
Cursor eventCursor = cr.query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, EVENT_PROJECTION, selection, null, null);
```

I have tried many ways but still no results...

Someone knows why it fails ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, not exactly the code from Google...

```
final String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[]{
    CalendarContract.Events._ID,
    CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,
    CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
    CalendarContract.Events.DTEND,
};

final int PROJECTION_ID_INDEX = 0;
final int PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX = 1;
final int PROJECTION_DTSTART_INDEX = 2;
final int PROJECTION_DTEND_INDEX = 3;

Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2020, 3, 18, 0, 0);
long startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2020, 3, 24, 0, 0);
long endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

String where = "((dtstart >= " + startMillis + ") AND (dtstart <= " + endMillis + ") AND (calendar_id = " + calID + "))";

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.READ_CALENDAR) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(Events.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.i (TAG, "ID=" + cursor.getLong(PROJECTION_ID_INDEX) + " Title=" + cursor.getString(PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

}
```